# Finding the largest $p$ and smallest $q$ such that $p≤P(A\cap B')≤q$

Tags: probability, statistics

Given that, $P(A) = 5/6$ and $P(B) = 1/3$

I'm having trouble finding the minimum value for this inequality. Finding the largest is quite easy and comes out to $2/3$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A\cap B') = P(A) - P(A\cap B) \ge P(A)-P(B) = \frac{1}{2}.$